# Glueing the metric

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry, geometric-topology

Let $(M,g)$ be a (smooth) compact Riemannian manifold with boundary. 
We glue the two copy of $M$, to make it closed Riemannian $M'$.

**Q** 1.Can we make a modify  $g$ near $\partial M$, such that there is 
a smooth metric $g'$ restricted on either 
copy,  it coincides with the modified  metric$g$.

I guess we  can do it by product some (smooth)positive-function.

PS: The earlier mistake is pointed by user10354138. Thanks.

Comment: If I'm understanding the question correctly, then yes.  Given a (not necessarily compact) Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ with boundary, there exists a Riemannian manifold without boundary $(\tilde{M},\tilde{g}$ which is an extension of $(M,g)$.  This manifold $\tilde{M}$ is the double of $M$, but the restriction is only agreeable with a single copy.  See the article "The smooth Riemannian extension problem" by Pigola and Veronelli.

Answer (score 2):

In general, no you can't, because the metric need not be smoothly compatible at the boundary, akin to $f(x)=|x|$ is not differentiable at 0, despite its restriction to both $(-\infty,0]$ and $[0,\infty)$ are analytic.

What you could do is to allow a little bit of room to smooth it out, so the restriction is $g$ away from a small tubular neighbourhood of the (original) boundary.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I have one question, the example you posted is on the non-compact manifold, and the glued manifold is not closed.

Comment: That is just the local model of how things could go wrong.  If you want a compact example, glue two semicircles together where away from the boundary the metric is usual, but near the boundary it looks like $const.(1+|\theta|)\,\mathrm{d}\theta^2$.